# Find limit of $a_n=\sqrt[n]{|(r_n)^n-h^n|}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Given $g>h>0$, $\lim_{n \to \infty}r_n = g$ and $a_n=\sqrt[n]{|(r_n)^n-h^n|}$. I have to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = g$. I noticed that $a_n \le \sqrt[n]{|r_n^n|+h^n}\le|r_n|$. What to do next?

Comment: How about tackling the simplified case that $r_n \equiv g$?  Proving that the limit is $g$ in that case will probably help you in the slightly more general case.

Answer (score 0):

If
$a_n=\sqrt[n]{|(r_n)^n-h^n|}$,
then
$\dfrac{a_n}{r_n}
=\sqrt[n]{|1-(h/r_n)^n|}
$.

Since
$r_n \to g$,
it is enough to show that
$\sqrt[n]{|1-(h/r_n)^n|}
\to 1$.
Since $g > h$,
for all large enough $n$
there is a $c < 1$ such that
$h/r_n < c$.

So,
if you can show that
$\sqrt[n]{1-c^n}
\to 1$,
you are done.

Since
$x^n < x$
for
$n >1$ and
$0 < x < 1$,
$x^{1/n} > x$.
Therefore
$\sqrt[n]{1-c^n}
\gt 1-c^n$.

All that is left
is to show that
$c^n \to 0$.

I will leave that to you.